# PHP SOAP calls not waiting for return

Tags: php, soap

Is there a way of creating a SOAP call in PHP that is not waiting for the called function to return?

I am calling a Magento Api function from my system to create a new product in the catalog. This can take quite a long time and I don't want my end user to wait until it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do just a normal call, but don't block the user doing other stuff during the call. This way you can have your cake (the call) and eat it (get the results).

Most common method would be to do an `AJAX` call: you do the request via script to the `PHP` file, but the interface will be responsive / usable. If the user doesn't browse from the page you did the request at, you can even serve a response.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do, but I'll use a worker instead of ajax as my soap call must be done after some php calculations.